# SVG text misplaced when using QSvgWidget

Tags: python, svg, text, pyside2, qtsvg

I have a fixed-size PySide2 window (800x480), which was created using pyside2-uic and an SVG file, containing some text, which was created in Inkscape in a matching 800mm x 480mm format. This is how it is supposed to look like (SVG converted to PNG with inkscape):

[image]

Now all I want is to show the SVG file within that PySide2 window on demand. I am using the following approach:

```
self.svgWidget = QtSvg.QSvgWidget('image.svg')
self.centralWidget.addWidget(self.svgWidget)
self.svgWidget.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 480)  # this basically does nothing here
self.svgWidget.show()
```

However there are two problems: First one is, that the SVG is shown within my window, but it has a ~10px margin to the window borders on every side (background is set to blue in the screenshot below for better visibility). I managed to work around this issue by setting the geometry in the centralwidgets PaintEvent (same code as the 'setGeometry' line above). For some reason it works without a margin then, but I don't understand why.

[image]

The second and more severe problem is, that all texts are misplaced as the screenshot above also shows. That happens no matter which method I try (with or without margin). What is the proper way to display an SVG file with texts?

---

SVG File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="800mm"
   height="480mm"
   viewBox="0 0 800.00001 480"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   inkscape:version="1.1.1 (3bf5ae0d25, 2021-09-20)"
   sodipodi:docname="image.svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview7"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     showgrid="false"
     width="800mm"
     inkscape:lockguides="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.25"
     inkscape:cx="986"
     inkscape:cy="1090"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="991"
     inkscape:window-x="-9"
     inkscape:window-y="-9"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="g2011"
     showguides="true"
     inkscape:guide-bbox="true"
     scale-x="1" />
  <defs
     id="defs2">
    <clipPath
       clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       id="clipPath18">
      <path
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="M 0,0 H 5184 V 1612.75 H 0 Z"
         id="path20-1" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath
       clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       id="clipPath18-7">
      <path
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="M 0,0 H 5184 V 1612.75 H 0 Z"
         id="path20-1-1" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath
       clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       id="clipPath18-3">
      <path
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="M 0,0 H 5184 V 1612.75 H 0 Z"
         id="path20-1-3" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Ebene 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <g
       id="g2011"
       transform="translate(0,311.99994)">
      <rect
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.430331"
         id="rect3147"
         width="800"
         height="480"
         x="0"
         y="-311.99994" />
      <rect
         style="fill:#00709b;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.429801"
         id="rect2986"
         width="764.77802"
         height="365.8175"
         x="17.777779"
         y="-215.59523" />
      <g
         id="g12"
         transform="matrix(0.08287486,0,0,-0.08272536,0,-200.88885)" />
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         x="221.45676"
         y="-120.65701"
         id="text4088"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan4090"
           x="221.45676"
           y="-120.65701"
           style="font-size:64.4116px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444">willkommen</tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3148"
         y="-82.160599"
         x="434.15173"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:64.4116px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444"
           y="-82.160599"
           x="434.15173"
           id="tspan3150"
           sodipodi:role="line">welcome</tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         x="196.16772"
         y="-77.140839"
         id="text3152"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan3154"
           x="196.16772"
           y="-77.140839"
           style="font-size:51.336px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444">bienvenue</tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3156"
         y="-16.451084"
         x="342.57492"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:44.1958px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444"
           y="-16.451084"
           x="342.57492"
           id="tspan3158"
           sodipodi:role="line">benvenuto</tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         x="231.16058"
         y="61.403408"
         id="text3160"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan3162"
           x="236.68501"
           y="61.403408"
           style="font-size:44.1958px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444">bienvenidos </tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3164"
         y="22.675707"
         x="212.45244"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:61.9871px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444"
           y="22.675707"
           x="212.45244"
           id="tspan3166"
           sodipodi:role="line">velkommen</tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         x="427.87759"
         y="108.65914"
         id="text3168"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan3170"
           x="427.87759"
           y="108.65914"
           style="font-size:57.2027px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444">bem-vindo</tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3172"
         y="-53.48719"
         x="461.78647"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:35.211px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444"
           y="-53.48719"
           x="461.78647"
           id="tspan3174"
           sodipodi:role="line">welkom</tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         x="331.01517"
         y="-46.486565"
         id="text3176"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan3178"
           x="331.01517"
           y="-46.486565"
           style="font-size:40.5671px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444">wëllkom</tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         x="404.07504"
         y="66.334152"
         id="text3180"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan3182"
           x="404.07504"
           y="66.334152"
           style="font-size:54.7956px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444">fáilte</tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3184"
         y="-20.466587"
         x="196.38995"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:31.5092px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444"
           y="-20.466587"
           x="196.38995"
           id="tspan3186"
           sodipodi:role="line">croeso</tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         x="173.7171"
         y="-47.405903"
         id="text3188"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan3190"
           x="173.7171"
           y="-47.405903"
           style="font-size:26.1531px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444">välkommen</tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3192"
         y="-19.886902"
         x="504.91022"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:41.4442px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444"
           y="-19.886902"
           x="510.0907"
           id="tspan3194"
           sodipodi:role="line">witajcie </tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         x="425.57166"
         y="18.807909"
         id="text3196"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan3198"
           x="430.75214"
           y="18.807909"
           style="font-size:41.4442px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444">vitajte </tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3204"
         y="92.614479"
         x="224.17757"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:31.6279px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444"
           y="92.614479"
           x="228.13103"
           id="tspan3206"
           sodipodi:role="line">dobrodošli </tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         x="520.99884"
         y="-123.48374"
         id="text3208"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan3210"
           x="526.73578"
           y="-123.48374"
           style="font-size:45.8956px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444">kalos ilthate </tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3212"
         y="104.91988"
         x="644.87781"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:7.98902px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.665751"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:34.2801px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.665751"
           y="104.91988"
           x="644.87781"
           id="tspan3214"
           sodipodi:role="line">hosgeldiniz</tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3216"
         y="119.13852"
         x="131.89622"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:25.2077px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444"
           y="119.13852"
           x="131.89622"
           id="tspan3218"
           sodipodi:role="line">bine aţi venit</tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         x="539.63635"
         y="6.8259072"
         id="text3220"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan3222"
           x="539.63635"
           y="6.8259072"
           style="font-size:27.5697px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444">tervetuloa</tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3224"
         y="66.219139"
         x="569.24097"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:37.5782px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444"
           y="66.219139"
           x="569.24097"
           id="tspan3226"
           sodipodi:role="line">tere tulemast</tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3228"
         y="35.52594"
         x="522.39667"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:33.5627px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444"
           y="35.52594"
           x="522.39667"
           id="tspan3230"
           sodipodi:role="line">vítejte</tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         x="667.24567"
         y="40.862556"
         id="text3232"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan3234"
           x="667.24567"
           y="40.862556"
           style="font-size:43.0259px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444">üdvözlöm</tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3236"
         y="-53.281906"
         x="592.6908"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:37.0441px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444"
           y="-53.281906"
           x="592.6908"
           id="tspan3238"
           sodipodi:role="line">velkomin</tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.09607px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.258006"
         x="633.43665"
         y="-99.416016"
         id="text3240"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan3242"
           x="633.43665"
           y="-99.416016"
           style="font-size:24.9883px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.258006">laipni lūdzam</tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3244"
         y="-33.706699"
         x="697.60974"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:28.5473px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444"
           y="-33.706699"
           x="697.60974"
           id="tspan3246"
           sodipodi:role="line">sveiki atvykę</tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         x="695.26349"
         y="-75.731087"
         id="text3248"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan3250"
           x="695.26349"
           y="-75.731087"
           style="font-size:28.5473px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444">merħba</tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3252"
         y="-11.484477"
         x="641.60974"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:28.5473px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444"
           y="-11.484477"
           x="641.60974"
           id="tspan3254"
           sodipodi:role="line">dobredojde</tspan></text>
      <text
         id="text3256"
         y="125.38598"
         x="347.12665"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-size:28.5473px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444"
           y="125.38598"
           x="347.12665"
           id="tspan3258"
           sodipodi:role="line">laskavo prosymo</tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.33333px;line-height:0%;font-family:NexusSansPro-Bold;-inkscape-font-specification:'NexusSansPro-Bold Bold';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.444444"
         x="629.10687"
         y="130.35851"
         id="text3260"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan3262"
           x="629.10687"
           y="130.35851"
           style="font-size:23.3507px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.444444">härzliche wöikomme</tspan></text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: https://svgur.com/s/bKy I hope that's okay. You'll notice that the font is different here. That's because I use a custom font-family (Nexus Sans Pro - Bold). But I checked and the font is properly loaded in my Python application (you can also see that by comparing the screenshot with the SVG->PNG conversion in the original post). So font shouldn't be the issue here...

Comment: The problem with the text seems to be that according to [QTBUG-11072](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-11072) "explicit positioning of tspans is not part of the [SVG Tiny 1.2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGMobile12), which is what Qt supports". I cannot reproduce the issue with the margins - for me, the image fills the whole window if I set the svg-widget as the central-widget of a QMainWindow. It looks like you must have added the svg-widget to a layout, which will have a default margin. If so, this can be adjusted with `layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: The SVG Tiny 1.2 restriction is really unfortunate... I also wasn't able to find an option in inkscape to save the SVG according to the Tiny 1.2 specification, so I just export the background as PNG now and use that instead. For the margins: Indeed I added the SVGWidget to a Layout of the central-widget, your line of code fixed it for one of my backgrounds. The problem is that I am adding two backgrounds, that need to get switched out at runtime: The second is hidden at start and then at runtime the first is hidden and the second shown. I assume I should instead remove the first then...